# How to find unused ram in kvm

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I run a QEMU instance with KVM. I know KVM can overcommit RAM but i want to see how much space i have left to overcommit without accessing all the VMs (which would take a lot of time and some contain private information). Ideally in a parseable way. I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and the VMs are a mix of Windows (with ballooning drivers) and Linux.

my machine has 128GB of RAM and the VMs have a total of 150GB allocated. I know this ram will only really be used once it is accessed for the first time but most VMs run programs that rapidly use and stop using a lot of memory. which causes the 128GB to be filled up quite fast. If i understand correctly KVM will free up unused memory once the host gets low on RAM.

Comment: What more details do you need than `free`?

Comment: if i understand correctly the `used` in `free` also includes memory that was once touched by the guest OS and is now free to be cleaned up. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: If a VM really isn't using the memory anymore, then the usage will go back down. But this doesn't always happen with Linux; see https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: It looks like that was indeed my issue. If you want to you can post it as a anwser and i will accept it. Is there any way to view this cache/available/used info on a VM without actually accessing it?